# What is the convention for creating Model names that have more than one word?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

```
rails generate model FooTable  name:string

rails generate model foo_table name:string
```

Which one is the correct way?

Comment: Both are correct. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-model p 2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either, they are equivalent. Both generate a model named `FooTable` using a database table called `foo_tables`.